# Pig: Load xml with nested objects

Tags: xml, apache-pig

The below xml contains Categories and Products. Categories i can load succesfully, but Products i cannot since there is an nested colours object in it. How i can handle this xml in pig?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Feed xmlns="http://www.xx.com/PRR/ProductFeed/1.0"
              name="xx"
              incremental="false"
              extractDate="2014-04-22T11:00:00.000000">
 <Categories>
  <Category>
   <ExternalId>2_5</ExternalId>
   <ParentExternalId></ParentExternalId>
   <Name>Baby</Name>
   <CategoryPageUrl>http://www.xx.com/en-US/Clearance/Baby-0-3yrs-Clothing.html</CategoryPageUrl>
  </Category>
  <Category>
   <ExternalId>2_3</ExternalId>
   <ParentExternalId></ParentExternalId>
   <Name>Boys 1½-12yrs</Name>
   <CategoryPageUrl>http://www.xx.com/en-US/Clearance/Boys-1H-12yrs-Clothing.html</CategoryPageUrl>
  </Category>
 </Categories>
 <Products>
  <Product>
   <ExternalId>78094</ExternalId>
   <Name>Sleep Bag</Name>
   <Description>A cover they can't throw off in the night. Pure cotton with one of our uniquely lovely prints. In its own gift box. An ultra thoughtful, luxurious present.</Description>
   <Brand>xx</Brand>
   <CategoryExternalId>1_5_1</CategoryExternalId>
   <ProductPageUrl>http://www.xx.com/en-US/Baby-0-3yrs-Accessories/78094/Baby-0-3yrs-Sleep-Bag.html</ProductPageUrl>
   <ImageUrl>http://www.xx.com/productimages/productThumb160x207/14USPR_78094_MUL.jpg</ImageUrl>
   <SwatchImageUrl>http://www.xx.com/productimages/grsw/14USPR_78094_MUL_s.jpg</SwatchImageUrl>
   <Price>54.0000</Price>
   <Wasprice>54.0000</Wasprice>
   <ManufacturerPartNumber></ManufacturerPartNumber>
   <EAN></EAN>
   <Colours>
    <Variation>
     <Tier2>MUL</Tier2>
     <Tier2Descr>Multi Elephant Party</Tier2Descr>
     <Tier2Url>http://www.xx.com/en-US/Baby-0-3yrs-Accessories/78094-MUL/Baby-0-3yrs-Multi-Elephant-Party-Sleep-Bag.html</Tier2Url>
     <Tier2ImageUrl>http://www.xx.com/productimages/productThumb160x207/14USPR_78094_MUL.jpg</Tier2ImageUrl>
     <Tier3>03 06</Tier3>
     <Tier3Descr>3-6m</Tier3Descr>
     <StockStatus>-2</StockStatus>
     <SwatchUrl>http://www.xx.com/productimages/grsw/14USPR_78094_MUL_s.jpg</SwatchUrl>
    </Variation>
    <Variation>
     <Tier2>MUL</Tier2>
     <Tier2Descr>Multi Elephant Party</Tier2Descr>
     <Tier2Url>http://www.xx.com/en-US/Baby-0-3yrs-Accessories/78094-MUL/Baby-0-3yrs-Multi-Elephant-Party-Sleep-Bag.html</Tier2Url>
     <Tier2ImageUrl>http://www.xx.com/productimages/productThumb160x207/14USPR_78094_MUL.jpg</Tier2ImageUrl>
     <Tier3>06 18</Tier3>
     <Tier3Descr>6-18m</Tier3Descr>
     <StockStatus>-2</StockStatus>
     <SwatchUrl>http://www.xx.com/productimages/grsw/14USPR_78094_MUL_s.jpg</SwatchUrl>
    </Variation>
   </Colours>
  </Product>
 </Products>
</Feed>
```

Pig script i use for categories:

```
REGISTER 'lib/pig/piggybank.jar'

raw = load '$INPUT_FEED' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Category') 
    as (x:chararray);

raw_category = foreach raw GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,
    '<Category>\\n\\s*<ExternalId>(.*)</ExternalId>\\n\\s*<ParentExternalId>(.*)</ParentExternalId>\\n\\s*<Name>(.*)</Name>\\n\\s*<CategoryPageUrl>(.*)</CategoryPageUrl>\\n\\s*</Category>'))
    as (external_id:chararray, parent_external_id:chararray, name:chararray, categorypageurl:chararray);
```

this is working properly, but how i can load products? the best would be the load category and product in one load statement, but worse case it is good in two parts as well.

thanks in advance

update:

finally i was able to define nested fields as well, but only works if there is only one variation under colours. If i use the above xml it returns an empty row. If i delete a variation under colours (so only one variation remains) then it gives back the raw correctly.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong? i am expecting to get back two rows from the above xml.

```
raw = load '$INPUT_FEED' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Product') 
    as (x:chararray);

raw_product = foreach raw GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,
    '<Product>\\n\\s*<ExternalId>(.*)</ExternalId>\\n\\s*<Name>(.*)</Name>\\n\\s*<Description>(.*)</Description>\\n\\s*<Brand>(.*)</Brand>\\n\\s*<CategoryExternalId>(.*)</CategoryExternalId>\\n\\s*<ProductPageUrl>(.*)</ProductPageUrl>\\n\\s*<ImageUrl>(.*)</ImageUrl>\\n\\s*<SwatchImageUrl>(.*)</SwatchImageUrl>\\n\\s*<Price>(.*)</Price>\\n\\s*<Wasprice>(.*)</Wasprice>\\n\\s*<ManufacturerPartNumber>(.*)</ManufacturerPartNumber>\\n\\s*<EAN>(.*)</EAN>\\n\\s*<Colours>\\n\\s*<Variation>\\n\\s*<Tier2>(.*)</Tier2>\\n\\s*<Tier2Descr>(.*)</Tier2Descr>\\n\\s*<Tier2Url>(.*)</Tier2Url>\\n\\s*<Tier2ImageUrl>(.*)</Tier2ImageUrl>\\n\\s*<Tier3>(.*)</Tier3>\\n\\s*<Tier3Descr>(.*)</Tier3Descr>\\n\\s*<StockStatus>(.*)</StockStatus>\\n\\s*<SwatchUrl>(.*)</SwatchUrl>\\n\\s*</Variation>\\n\\s*</Colours>\\n\\s*</Product>')) 
    as (external_id:chararray, name:chararray, description:chararray, brand:chararray, category_external_id:chararray, product_page_url:chararray, image_url:chararray, swatch_image_url:chararray, price:float, wasprice:float, manufacturer_part_number:chararray, ean:chararray, tier2:chararray, tier2desc:chararray, tier2url:chararray, tier2imageurl:chararray, tier3:chararray, tier3desc:chararray, stockstatus:chararray, swatchurl:chararray);
```

Comment: Are you saying if you do the same for products as another load statement it will not work. raw = load '$INPUT_FEED' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Product') 
    as (x:chararray);

Comment: yes, since it has also colours nested array and i don't know how to define those fields.

Comment: now i was able to define nested fields as well, but only works if nested array has only one element, if more then one returns empty row.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a big problem with processing xml through pig if a xml contain namespaces.This feature is not yet supported by piggybank's Xpath(I am using the latest version piggybank0.14). Also, nested path traversal is not feasible currently(ex - /book/author/name) returns blank value.

They are exactly developing a feature in pig0.15 : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4355

Here they have introduced the condition to check namespaces and XpathAll UDF which resolves the above issues but this version is not released yet. Though a patch is available at https://github.com/apache/pig/pull/14.

Another option is you, can add your own UDF using python or any other language you are comfortable with, that parses your particular usecase.